# Test Case Not covering a branch

Tags: java, groovy, kotlin, spock

I have a code which calculates age of a person and takes some action based on the result.

```
age = calculateAge();

if (age <= 30 || (age > 30 && city="newyork")){
println("Welcome")
}
```

I have test cases written in Spock with  all possible values of age & city

```
25|Newyork
25|London
30|Newyork
30|London
35|Newyork
35|London
```

But still one of the branch is missing.
    It gets covered if I change age <=30 to age < 30.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `city="newyork"` is an assignment

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `age > 30` check is redundant - there is no situation where it will ever be executed in this scenario and return false. If execution gets to this point, the condition will return true, as it will only execute this if `age <= 30` is false. This occurs because `||` is a 'short circuit' operator, which means (for '||') that it only executes the right hand side if the left hand side is false (as if the left hand side is true, the result of the 'or' operation is true irrespective of the result of the right hand side.

The same (in an inverted sense) is true of the `&&` operator, except in this case it only executes the right hand side if the left hand side is true, as if it the left hand side if false, the result of `&&` must also be false, regardless of the result of the right hand side.

You can replace this check with:

```
if (age <= 30 || city == "newyork") {
   println("Welcome")
}
```

and you will have the same functionality and all branches will be covered.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and detailed explanation. This makes sense. Let me make the change and test it.